# Trying to pass the id parameter into a VF page that is part of the opportunity layout

Tags: visualforce, controller, controller-extension

There is an object called milestones__c that is a child of the opportunity.  I am trying to retrieve the milestones of a given opportunity and display them.

Here is my controller extension

```
public class MilestoneSwimlaneController{
    private final ID opp;
    public MilestoneSwimlaneController(ApexPages.StandardController oppcontroller) {
       opp =  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }
    List<Milestone__c> miles = [Select id from milestone__c where Opportunity_milestones__c = :opp]; 
    Public List<Milestone__c> getmiles(){
        return miles;
    }
}
```

the variable opp is not picking up the opportunity id like i am expecting it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is being called before the controller's constructor. You should move the query inside the constructor after getting the ID:

```
public class MilestoneSwimlaneController{
    private final ID opp;
    List<Milestone__c> miles;
    public MilestoneSwimlaneController(ApexPages.StandardController oppcontroller) {
       opp =  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
       miles = [Select id from milestone__c where Opportunity_milestones__c = :opp];
    }
    Public List<Milestone__c> getmiles(){
        return miles;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the last part of the controller can't see the variable miles.  Getting a compiler error Variable does not exist miles line 9 which happens to be  return miles

Comment: @A.Noland Start with my code exactly; there shouldn't be any compilation errors. I suspect that you may have put the variable's declaration inside the constructor.